# Dropdown menu looks different in every browser

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

I just finished creating a drop down menu, but the drop down menu looks a bit different on each browser. Here is the demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/siw58v7o

Firefox browser: http://bildeopplaster.no/3-c This is how it's supposed to look like

**EDIT:** Works in chrome now

Chrome browser: http://bildeopplaster.no/3-d Here you can see that there is some spacing on the first sub text

**EDIT:** It's still the same in Safari. I can't figure out where and what in the code I need to change, any help?

Safari browser: http://bildeopplaster.no/3-e Here the first sub text is underneath the category text

What do I need to do to make it same in all browsers?

HTML code:

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <!-- MEN'S WEAR BUTTON -->

      <li class="menswear"><a href="#">MEN'S WEAR</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Boots</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Scarves</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">SALE</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav
```

CSS code:

```
     /* ------------------ NAVIGATION ------------------ */
    .navigation {


      position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 1024px;
        height: 42px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    }

    .navigation a {
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
          -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
           -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
            -o-transition: all .25s ease;
               transition: all .25s ease;
    }


    /* ------------------ MEN'S WEAR BUTTON ------------------ */

    .menswear { 
      width:130px !important;
      height: 42px;
      float:left;
      list-style: none;
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
     }

     .menswear:hover {
      background: #000;
     }

     .menswear ul {
      overflow:hidden;
      background:black;
      opacity: 0.5px;
      width:1024px;
      height:300px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: relative;
      top:26px;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
           -o-transition: all .25s ease;
              transition: all .25s ease;  
    }

    .menswear ul {
      overflow:hidden;
      background: #000;
      opacity: 0.5px;
      width:1024px;
      height:300px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: relative;
      top:26px;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
           -o-transition: all .25s ease;
              transition: all .25s ease;  
    }
    .menswear:hover ul { visibility: visible; opacity: 0.9; }

    .menswear a {
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      top: 12px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 9px 15px 11px 14px;
      color: #000;
    }

    .menswear a:hover:nth-child(1) { color: #fff; }
    .menswear li { background: transparent; }

    .dropdown1:nth-child(1) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      right: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 96px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(2) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(3) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-right: -20px;  
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(4) {

      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 63px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-top: 1px;
    }
    .dropdown1:nth-child(5) {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      top: 0px;
      right: 30px;
      left: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 1px;
    }

    .dropdown1 a {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #888;
    }

    .dropdown1 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #fff; }
    .dropdown1 a:nth-child(1) { color: #cbcbcb; }

    .dropdown1 ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
      position: relative;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .dropdown1 ul li {
      position: relative;
      padding: 8px;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 5px;
      font-size: 13.5px;
    }

    .dropdown1 ul li a { font-weight: normal; }

    .dropdown1 ul li a:hover { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: the links i posted is actually how the drop down menu looks, i had to remove the other buttons in the demo so the code could be less then 3000 characters in the post, but it looks the same with the rest of the buttons too

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it in Chrome. (Changing padding from 15px to 0)

```
.dropdown1 ul {
    paddning: 0;
}
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/qezkkref

Comment: Just tested this on a ML machine with Safari 6.0.1 which seems to work as expected. Though it may differ i later versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Just the following code into your CSS file. Hope this will work.**

```
.dropdown1 ul li, .dropdown1 ul li a{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: if i add `float` all the text in the drop down menu disappears except the first topwear section